# Retrieve values from xml - c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following xml file from an API,

```
<IPInformation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.com/">
<City>xxxxxx</City>
<StateProvince>12</StateProvince>
<Country>xxxxxx</Country>
<Organization/>
<Latitude>13.0833</Latitude>
<Longitude>80.28329</Longitude>
<AreaCode>0</AreaCode>
<TimeZone/>
<HasDaylightSavings>false</HasDaylightSavings>
<Certainty>90</Certainty>
<RegionName/>
<CountryCode>xx</CountryCode>
</IPInformation>
```

I need to get the `Latitude` and `Longitude` values from above xml and store it in a string.

I am working on c# .net 3.5 framework,  I tried the below code,

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
location = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//City");
latitude = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//Latitude");
```

I am always getting `Null` instead of `13.0833` and `80.28329`.

Can any one tell me how to retrieve the `Latitude` and `Longitude` values from above xml.

Thanks

Comment: Deserialize it to an object of type IPInformation.. Use the OOP way..

Comment: Good point; however, it does not explain why the curren approach does not work as expected.

Comment: What is the type of the variables `latitude` and `longitude`? The method `SelectSingleNode` does not parse the content of the selected node; its return type is `XmlNode`, which has to be process further to achieve parsing.

Comment: Just read briefly, but this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696745/using-selectsinglenode-with-xpath-returns-null

Comment: @Codor -- but the `SelectSingleNode` call returns null...

Comment: BTW try this webpage for testing XPath expressions [link](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the namespace. I copied your XML into `a.xml` and following works (LINQpad):

```
void Main()
{
    var a = @"c:\temp\a\a.xml";
    XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument();
    x.Load(a);

    var ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(x.NameTable);
    ns.AddNamespace("x", x.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
    x.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//x:Longitude", ns).Dump();

}
```

prints

```
<Longitude xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.com/">80.28329</Longitude>
```

Comment: I am getting the following error while build the app "Error 'System.Xml.XmlNode' does not contain a definition for 'Dump' and no extension method 'Dump' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.XmlNode' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: `Dump` is a LINQPad command. Try running `Console.WriteLine(x.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//x:Longitude", ns))` or `Console.WriteLine(x.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//x:Longitude", ns).InnerText);`

Comment: xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//x:Longitude", ns).InnerXml.ToString(); - worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For a start you have two xmlns attribute declarations in your xml - if you remove `xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.com/"` and change your query to `/IPInformation/Latitude` that gives you back a valid XMLNode.

Comment: No, there are no two xmlns attributes. The `xmlns` is the default namespace.