# Null reference exception in xml - C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to get the country, lat/long, timezone etc from an api using public ip.

Below is the xml response i am getting from api,

```
<IPInformation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.com/">
<City>Chennai</City>
<StateProvince>25</StateProvince>
<Country>India</Country>
<Organization/>
<Latitude>13.0833</Latitude>
<Longitude>80.28329</Longitude>
<AreaCode>0</AreaCode>
<TimeZone/>
<HasDaylightSavings>false</HasDaylightSavings>
<Certainty>90</Certainty>
<RegionName/>
<CountryCode>IN</CountryCode>
</IPInformation>
```

I am loading the response in xml file, from there using `SelectSingleNode` i am trying to get the country value. But always i am getting `nullreferenceexception`.

Below is the code i have tried,

```
if (response.StatusCode.ToString().ToLower() == "ok")
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
    XmlNode msgnode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//Country"); -->getting null here
    string msgname = msgnode.InnerText;                                      
}
```

tried below one,

```
String country = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("IPInformation/Country").Value;
```

`SelectSingleNode` always return a null value

Full stactrace:

```
at SingleScanPalletTag.MobileClient.ScanOutMenu.GetGeoLocation()
   at SingleScanPalletTag.MobileClient.ScanOutMenu.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog(IntPtr hwnModal)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
   at SingleScanPalletTag.MobileClient.Program.Main()
```

[image]

Can any one tell me how to get the country,latitude and longitude value from the above xml.

Please help me.

Comment: It's unclear from your question and code comments exactly where the `NullReferenceException` is being thrown from.  Does the `SelectSingleNode` line throw an exception or return a `null` that leads to a `NullReferenceException` in the next line?

Comment: @adv12 SelectSingleNode return a null value

Comment: Please Show us the full stacktrace.

Comment: @etalon11 added full stacktrace in question

Comment: If you put a watch on xmlDoc, is the xml you expect present?

Comment: County is not a node. It's a simple element. You could even serialize the XML into an object. I personally prefer this way. So if your XML has always the same structure, You could make a class of that Type and create an object with serialization.

Comment: @StingyJack xml is not present at xmlDoc.DocumentElement, but i can see it on xmlDoc.innerXml, i have attached the screen for reference

Comment: @user2681579 did you have success?

Answer (score 1):

What about to user XDocument() from System.Xml.Linq?
Assuming that this xml file isn't a tree...

```
XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument();
var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());

var strCountry = xmlDoc.Root.Element("Country");
```

if the xml have children, use `xmlDoc.Root.Descendants()`

Answer (score 0):

If I had more reputation I would have added a comment pointing you to this [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089196/selectsinglenode-returning-null-for-known-good-xml-node-path-using-xpath) but I can't create comments yet so it has to be an answer.

This is probably a duplicate so if someone can flag it, please do.

This has to do with the namespaces, specifically the `xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.com/"` part.

Create a `XmlNamespaceManager` and add the namespace.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNamespaceManager namespaces = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
namespaces.AddNamespace("ns", "http://ws.cdyne.com/");
xmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
XmlNode msgnode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/ns:IPInformation/ns:Country",namespaces);
string msgname = msgnode.InnerText;
```

Comment: @user2681579 If you found any of the answers useful, please mark them as answer.