# How to set attribute value for existing XML element

Tags: c#, xml

I have an existing XML file and I would like to update some of its attributes. I googled and see many similar questions and answers but I have no luck.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<system ExportDate="2/15/2018" ExportTime="11:56 AM EST" DateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy" NumberFormat="HH:mm:ss " SchemaValidation="true" ExportVersion="2016.1.SP1710.57 [Build 82] - 27 September 2017 (01:30 IST)" xmlns="http://www.mentor.com/harness/Schema/LibrarySchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mentor.com/harness/Schema/LibrarySchema file:/C:/MentorGraphics/VeSys_Client/dtd/LibrarySchema.xsd" XMLVersion="1.6">
  <librarymaterial librarymaterial_id="XXX" description="YYY" materialcode="ZZZ" />
 </system>
```

I am trying to set new values for some of the attributes.
For the root, I have no issue

```
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("ExportDate", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("ExportTime", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + " EST");
```

However, when I try the different methods but no hope

**Method 1:**

```
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/system/librarymaterial");
node.Attributes["librarymaterial_id"].Value=_librarymaterial_id;
```

**Error:**

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

node was null.

**Method 2:**

```
var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/system/librarymaterial");
foreach (XmlElement n in nodes)
{
    n.SetAttribute("librarymaterial_id", _librarymaterial_id);
}
```

This does not create an error, but the `librarymaterial_id` does not get updated.

Comment: Note that `system` has a namespace. You need a namespace manager

Comment: @ThomasWeller thanks for correcting me. I deleted my comment.

Comment: As @ThomasWeller pointed out, you'll require a namespace manager to do so, kindly go through this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1089210/4222487

Comment: I am setting it up now - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        XmlNodeList dataNodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("librarymaterial");

        for (int i = 0; i < dataNodes.Count; i++)
        {
            XmlAttribute attr = dataNodes[i].Attributes["librarymaterial_id"];
            attr.Value = "USA";
        }
```

Try this code.

Comment: it works so there are at least 2 solutions to the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Once you have list of nodes in a variable, you can play around with it. Hence there can be multiple solutions to the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: Nooooo! Why loop through all nodes and then modify the first one n times?

Comment: Typeo, please check now